# How can I disable the need for an event to have specific date in Fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I was going through Fullcanlendar's documentation to try to find a way to disable the need to enter a specific date from the calendar year to create an event. What I am looking for is a simple calendar option that only shows events on a weekly basis, and does not ask for a specific date such has November 25th. Basically, a calendar that works only in terms of Weekdays: Friday, thursday, etc. Is there an option for this?

Comment: An event must be attached to a date in FullCalendar. If you'd want to set "recurring" events, Its not possible directly, but there are [solution hints here](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/387) to achieve it server-side.

Answer (score 1):

example to call event on fullCalendar's event or click on date cell.

```
$(element).fullCalendar({
    dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
        var newDate = new Date(date.format());     
        return ((maxDate < newDate) ? '' : someFunctionCall(date.format('YYYY-MM-DD')));                
    },

    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {                
       var date = calEvent.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
       someFunctionCall(date);                   
    }
});
```

dayClick is called when the user clicks on a day (calendar cell).

eventClick is called when the user clicks an event.

**calEvent** is an Event Object that holds the event's information (date, title, etc).

**jsEvent** holds the native JavaScript event with low-level information such as click coordinates. Within the callback function, this is set to the event's `<div>` element.

**date** holds a moment object for the clicked day.

**view** holds the current View info like name, title etc..

using these two event functions you can implement what you actually want to implement.. Hope this answer helped you.